Mahasi walking meditation noting precision
When being mindful in Mahasi walking meditation, should the meditator walk very slowly in order to get time enough to fit the noting in? What should the meditator's attitude be if they skip a mantra note? Should one strain hard to get the prechosen mantra note right? How should one approach mistakes? What kind of concentration is needed? Is it enough to just be mindful with superficial concentration or must a high degree of concentration be developed? With momentary concentration, can the meditator get stuck to an object like with non-momentary concentration? What would right-concentration be with this kind of walking meditation practice?

Mahasi walking meditation is a basic training to help stabilize the mind (but not a Sutta training).
To dwell on a mistake is another mistake. Mistakes should be let go of, immediately, and the mind should return to the task of the walking meditation.
However Mahasi walking meditation is not Right Concentration. Right concentration has 'letting go' ('vossagga') as its object (SN 48.10).

Mistakes should be let go of immediately? Right but what if you do that but your a beginner and their is a nagging feeling that you're doing something wrong? If you don't have a teacher, what do you do? Possibly develop a bad habit?  What do you think about momentary concentration?

The training of meditation is to return to the task and abandon any nagging feelings. As for momentary concentration, this is to be developed.
